# Using VBA Macro +buttons to move back and forward through excel sheets, hidden sheets in sequence disrupting functionality

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pair of buttons ('continue' and 'back') which move a user forward and back worksheets.

The forward button seems to be able to move forward through visible sheets with no trouble, skipping hidden sheets fine.

The back button however, fails to do anything if there is a hidden sheet between the active sheet and the previous visible sheets.

I'm confused because the code for the two is practically identical:

Forward: (works fine)

```
Sub MoveNext()
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Back: (fails at hidden sheet)

```
Sub MoveBack()
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Activate
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Each button is bound to the subs above as suitable.

Comment: +1 nice question; just a note, `On Error Resume Next` should be followed by `On Error Goto 0` immediately after the line that you expect an error on - `Resume Next` essentially disables error trapping altogether (i.e. it *propagates* beyond `End Sub`) and can cause headaches if your VBA project is just a little more complex than that.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the advice, I'm new to VBA so appreciate these kind of tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting! It looks like if you try to activate a hidden worksheet, it defaults to the next highest index. So that's why it works going up, but not going down. I wrote a routine that checks whether there's a lower visible sheet, and if so, moves to it:

```
Sub MoveBack()
Dim PrevVisibleIndex As Long

PrevVisibleIndex = ActiveSheet.Index
With ThisWorkbook
    Do
        PrevVisibleIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(PrevVisibleIndex - 1, 1)
    Loop Until .Worksheets(PrevVisibleIndex).Visible = True Or PrevVisibleIndex = 1
    .Worksheets(PrevVisibleIndex).Activate
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to write a work around for me. Interesting re: explanation for why these seemingly symetric functions weren't behaving as well, good to know.